# How could I change an HTML header through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, let's say I have this HTML code, and I want to change the header from within the js code, how would I? I've tried several other solutions from other Q&As but they don't seem to work, either I'm brain dead or stuck. I want to change the header based on a variable, so something like:

```
header = variablexyz;
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .header {
            padding: 60px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #1746c7;
            color: white;
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
        <p>-randomly generated username-</p>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? The text inside the `h1` tag that reads 'header', the class header, or the css rule `header`? And what is the variable value - different text, a new class or a new class rule?

Comment: I'm trying to change the text inside the h1 tag that reads "header" to a different text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign an ID to the h1 containing the header

```js
const customHeader1 = "custom header";
const header1 = document.getElementById('header1').textContent = customHeader1;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .header {
      padding: 60px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #1746c7;
      color: white;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<head>
  <style>
    .header {
      padding: 60px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #1746c7;
      color: white;
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="header1">header</h1>
    <p>-randomly generated username-</p>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This quite simple `let header = document.getElementById('header') header.innerHTML = "Hello"`

Please assign a class name or ID to your header `<h1 id="idhere">`

Answer (score 2):

To change the text inside the `h1` tag (or any element) in javascript, you first make a reference to the element. As your `h1` tag has no `id` attribute, you instead reference a `collection` of all `h1` elements and reference the first (only) one using an array-like index [0]. You can then sets its innerText property to the variable holding the text you want to display.

Working snippet:

```js
let header = "some different Text";

const h1elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

h1elements[0].innerText = header;
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
        <p>-randomly generated username-</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to assign your header an ID
as such:
in you HTML

in your JavaScript
header = document.getElementById('header-id');
header.innerHTML = "HERE GOES THE CHANGE YOU WANT TO MAKE ON THE HEADER"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).